# Python dictionary keys. "In" complexity

Tags: python, dictionary, hashmap, complexity-theory, big-o

Quick question to mainly satisfy my curiosity on the topic.

I am writing some large python programs with an SQlite database backend and will be dealing with a large number of records in the future, so I need to optimize as much as I can.

For a few functions, I am searching through keys in a dictionary. I have been using the "in" keyword for prototyping and was planning on going back and optimizing those searches later as I know the "in" keyword is generally O(n) (as this just translates to python iterating over an entire list and comparing each element). But, as a python dict is basically just a hash map, is the python interpreter smart enough to interpret:

```
if(key in dict.keys()):
    ...code...
```

to:

```
if(dict[key] != None):
    ...code...
```

It is basically the same operation but the top would be O(n) and the bottom would be O(1).

It's easy for me to use the bottom version in my code, but then I was just curious and thought I would ask.

Comment: I say do what is easiest, and profile later.

Comment: Actually, the code on bottom wouldn't work. You have to do something akin to `try: dict[key]; except KeyError: pass; else: #...code...`.

Comment: @TravisGD This is a good point, I forgot about that

Comment: @jh314 This is true, but it's always in the back of my mind

Comment: As a side note: Don't wrap `if` conditions in unnecessary parentheses. People who read and write a lot of Python expect parentheses to mean something—a tuple, a genexp, or overriding operator precedence—and they'll have to stop and read each line twice to make sure your parens don't actually mean anything.

Comment: Another side note: Don't name a dictionary `dict`—that hides the type and constructor of the same name, which you may well want to use later on.

Comment: Out of curiosity: If you're using a sqlite backend, why do you have a large dict in the first place? If it's being used for caching database results, I've found that it's sometimes very hard to beat just using the database (or a second in-memory database) for that, unless you can tolerate the cache being out of date. More importantly, often the database is fast enough in the first place. Of course your mileage may vary, but definitely profile before wasting a lot of effort building something that will make your code harder to test and maintain…

Answer (score 160, accepted):

First, `key in d.keys()` is guaranteed to give you the same value as `key in d` for any dict `d`.

And the `in` operation on a `dict`, or the `dict_keys` object you get back from calling `keys()` on it (in 3.x), is *not* O(N), it's O(1).

There's no real "optimization" going on; it's just that using the hash is the obvious way to implement `__contains__` on a hash table, just as it's the obvious way to implement `__getitem__`.

---

You may ask where this is guaranteed.

Well, it's not. [Mapping Types](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict) defines `dict` as, basically, a hash table implementation of [`collections.abc.Mapping`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Mapping). There's nothing stopping someone from creating a hash table implementation of a Mapping, but still providing O(N) searches. But it would be extra work to make such a bad implementation, so why would they?

If you really need to prove it to yourself, you can test every implementation you care about (with a profiler, or by using some type with a custom `__hash__` and `__eq__` that logs calls, or…), or read the source.

---

In 2.x, you do not want to call `keys`, because that generates a `list` of the keys, instead of a `KeysView`. You could use `iterkeys`, but that may generate an iterator or something else that's not O(1). So, just use the dict itself as a sequence.

Even in 3.x, you don't want to call `keys`, because there's no need to. Iterating a `dict`, checking its `__contains__`, and in general treating it like a sequence is *always* equivalent to doing the same thing to its keys, so why bother? (And of course building the trivial `KeyView`, and accessing through it, are going to add a few nanoseconds to your running time and a few keystrokes to your program.)

(It's not quite clear that using sequence operations is equivalent for `d.keys()`/`d.iterkeys()` and `d` in 2.x. Other than performance issues, they *are* equivalent in every CPython, Jython, IronPython, and PyPy implementation, but it doesn't seem to be stated anywhere the way it is in 3.x. And it doesn't matter; just use `key in d`.)

---

While we're at it, note that this:

```
if(dict[key] != None):
```

… is not going to work. If the `key` is not in the `dict`, this will raise `KeyError`, not return `None`.

Also, you should never check `None` with `==` or `!=`; always use `is`.

You can do this with a `try`—or, more simply, do `if dict.get(key, None) is not None`. But again, there's no reason to do so. Also, that won't handle cases where `None` is a perfectly valid item. If that's the case, you need to do something like `sentinel = object(); if dict.get(key, sentinel) is not sentinel:`.

---

So, the right thing to write is:

```
if key in d:
```

---

More generally, this is not true:

> I know the "in" keyword is generally O(n) (as this just translates to python iterating over an entire list and comparing each element

The `in` operator, like most other operators, is just a call to a `__contains__` method (or the equivalent for a C/Java/.NET/RPython builtin). `list` implements it by iterating the list and comparing each element; `dict` implements it by hashing the value and looking up the hash; `blist.blist` implements it by walking a B+Tree; etc. So, it could be O(n), O(1), O(log n), or something completely different.

Comment: That's what I was thinking, is this documented anywhere? I wasn't sure though just because I though dict.keys() may just be returning a list. Making the "in" O(n)

Comment: @tknickman: In general, Python doesn't document performance characteristics of its functions. (Partly this is because it's always possible for you to do something ridiculous like define a `hash` function that depends on the number of elements.) So, [this](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict) is all you get. But the fact that it documents that dicts are hash tables implies pretty strongly that `key in d`, `d[key]`, and `d.get(key)` are all going to be O(1).

Comment: *Average* case is O(1), worst case O(n).

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: They are guaranteed to be semantically equivalent. In Python 3.x, they're also equivalent as far as performance. In Python 2.x, `keys` will obviously be slower. I've edited the answer to give more details. But the real point is, there is never any reason to use `key in d.keys()`, so you don't have to remember the details.

Comment: The first fallback solution I would try, if *key in dict* is not available, would be *dict.has_key()* instead of self written exception branches.

Answer (score 18):

In Python 2 `dict.keys()` creates the whole list of keys first that's why it is an `O(N)` operation, while `key in dict` is an `O(1)` operation.

`if(dict[key] != None)` will raise `KeyError` if key is not found in the dict, so it is not equivalent to the first code.

Python 2 results:

```
>>> dic = dict.fromkeys(range(10**5))
>>> %timeit 10000 in dic
1000000 loops, best of 3: 170 ns per loop
>>> %timeit 10000 in dic.keys()
100 loops, best of 3: 4.98 ms per loop
>>> %timeit 10000 in dic.iterkeys()
1000 loops, best of 3: 402 us per loop
>>> %timeit 10000 in dic.viewkeys()
1000000 loops, best of 3: 457 ns per loop
```

In Python 3 `dict.keys()` returns a view object which is quite faster than Python 2's `keys()` but still slower simple normal `key in dict`:

Python 3 results:

```
>>> dic = dict.fromkeys(range(10**5))
>>> %timeit 10000 in dic
1000000 loops, best of 3: 295 ns per loop
>>> %timeit 10000 in dic.keys()
1000000 loops, best of 3: 475 ns per loop
```

Use just:

```
if key in dict:
   #code
```

Comment: This is 2.x-specific. (Also, note that in CPython 2.7.3 or PyPy 2.0b1, `iterkeys` may be much faster than `keys`—Python 2.x allows `iterkeys` to be something smarter that just `iter(d.keys())`, and they actually do take some advantage. But it's still nowhere near as fast as just using `d` directly. On my computer, it's 94ns vs. 338us vs. 2.03ms.)

Answer (score 11):

The proper way to do this would be

```
if key in dict:
    do stuff
```

the **in** operator is O(1) for dictionaries and sets in python.

Answer (score 1):

The in operator for dict has average case time-complexity of O(1). For detailed information about time complexity of other dict() methods, visit this [link](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.