# Python fast contains method

Tags: python, dictionary, key, contains

If I have a dictionary in Python, what is the time complexity of searching for a non-existent key?

```
d = {}
if key not in d:
   print "Key not found!"
```

Does `in` do a linear search across the array of keys?

Is there an O(1) implementation of searching a data structure for a particular string? Effectively for a `contains()` method.

Comment: Dictionaries are based on a hash table which is O(1) for lookups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It must be amortised `O(1)` for a dictionary, because in the end the `in` operator is just performing a membership lookup, the `not` doesn't have an additional overhead on that. Take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17539423/201359) for further details regarding the time complexity of the `in` operator in the case of a dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

It's O(1) dictionary is implemented as a hash table and in does hash table lookup

Answer (score 1):

Dictionaries are *usually* O(1) for lookups.

It's perfectly acceptable to have a class that returns a constant for it's hash, but this degrades dictionary lookups to be linear.

eg.

```
class dumbint(int):
    def __hash__(self):
        return 0

$ python -m timeit -s 'class dumbint(int):__hash__ = lambda x:0' -s 'd={dumbint(i):i for i in range(100)}' 'dumbint(-1) in d'
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.64 usec per loop
$ python -m timeit -s 'class dumbint(int):__hash__ = lambda x:0' -s 'd={dumbint(i):i for i in range(1000)}' 'dumbint(-1) in d'
10000 loops, best of 3: 31.7 usec per loop
$ python -m timeit -s 'class dumbint(int):__hash__ = lambda x:0' -s 'd={dumbint(i):i for i in range(10000)}' 'dumbint(-1) in d'
1000 loops, best of 3: 803 usec per loop
```

strings have a good hash function, so you'll get O(1) lookups for exact matches. Searching for a *substring* in the keys is a much more difficult problem.