# What is the complexity of calling of dict.keys() in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, time-complexity, asymptotic-complexity

What's the asymptotic complexity of `dict.keys()` in python?

I found [this website](http://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) but it does not have the answer. I am using Python 3, but I guess this is not version specific.

Comment: It's `O(1)`, but requires one additional function call.

Comment: It is version specific in that with Python 2 `keys()` returns a list and in Python 3 it returns a dictionary view object.

Comment: Are you looking at an operation in dict.keys() such as in or the generation itself of the dictionary view?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python dictionary keys. "In" complexity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17539367/python-dictionary-keys-in-complexity)

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate - the other question is about `in` on dicts, this is about the method itself. They're closely related but not the same.

Comment: I am using this to get a list or other iterator to go through the dict and delete some keys. Currently casting the result of .keys() to a list.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Python 3, `dict.keys()` returns a [view object](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects). Essentially, this is just a window directly onto the dictionary's keys. There is no looping over the hashtable to build a new object, for example. This makes calling it a constant-time, that is O(1), operation.

View objects for dictionaries are implemented starting [here](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/d8f48717b74e/Objects/dictobject.c#l3102); the creation of new view objects uses [`dictview_new`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/d8f48717b74e/Objects/dictobject.c#l3137). All that this function does is create the new object that points back at the dictionary and increase reference counts (for garbage tracking).

In Python 2, `dict.keys()` returns a list object. To create this new list, Python must loop over the hashtable, putting the dictionary's keys into the list. This is implemented as the function [`dict_keys`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Objects/dictobject.c#l1221). The time complexity here is linear with the size of the dictionary, that is O(n), since every slot in the table must be visited.

N.B. `dict.viewkeys()` in Python 2 does the same as `dict.keys()` in Python 3.