# How to customize 'has_key' or 'in' method of a Python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a python dictionary that has objects as keys.
The objects have certain attributes say:

class Ex:
text
count
id

How do I enable constant time searching for an object with value equal to some text 'xyz'

Ex obj1
Ex obj2
Ex obj3
map = {obj1 : 1, obj2 : 2, obj3 : 3}

I want to know whether the 'has_key' or 'in' method of Python dictionary can achieve fetching objects with a particular attribute in constant time,i.e.,

map.has_key('xyz') will return me the presence of the corresponding object with text attribute as 'xyz' in constant time.

Comment: Already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17539367/python-dictionary-keys-in-complexity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement a `__hash__` function for that class as well as a `__eq__` method.

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, bar, bazz):
        self.bar = bar
        self.bazz = bazz

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash((self.bar, self.bazz))

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return (self.bar, self.bazz) == (other.bar, other.bazz)
```

That is assuming you want it to work such that `Foo(5, 'a') == Foo(5, 'a')`. But if you care solely about identity of objects (`foo is bar`) then you don't need to do anything at all, it will be `O(1)` already.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got what I wanted.

Comment: No problem. If you wouldn't mind could you mark my answer as correct.