# python dictionary checking with key

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to check whether my key is equal to the input:

```
topics = c.classify("what about ")
a = topics.keys() 
if a == "resources": 
    print("yes")
```

But `a` is stored as dict_keys(['resource"])
I want `a` to be just "resources".
can anyone help me on this,please?

Comment: Do you know for sure that this dict has only one key? Maybe just `if "resources" in topics`.

Comment: It appears that you're asking how to access an element of a sequence.  That's a simple subscript: `a = topics.keys()[0]`

Comment: @Prune it isn't a sequence in this case, though.

Comment: What is your long-term problem?  This seems an inelegant way to do most useful things.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: it appears to be a list of a single string, no?

Comment: a = topics.keys()[0] is giving error as TypeError: 'dict_keys' object does not support indexing @prune

Comment: @Prune nah, it's a `dict_keys` object, they are using Python 3

Comment: Ah ... which is solved with list(...)

Comment: Do you just want to check if `"resources"` is *a* key? That's `if "resources" in topics:`.

Answer (score 1):

You should first convert the keys into regular python list and then iterate in it (You probably can do it without converting, but I think it is more simple to find).

```
topics = c.classify("what about ")
a = list(topics.keys())
for key in a:
    if key == "resources": 
        print("yes")
```

Don't forget a dict can have multiple values.
As @rob-bricheno said, you can do it simpler with `in` operator. This operator will loop through the `list` and if the element you've specified is in it, return `True`, otherwise it will return `False` value. So you can do it with this simplified code:

```
topics = c.classify("what about ")
a = list(topics.keys())
if "resources" in a:
    print("yes")
```

When `resources` is in the `a` list, if condition is `True`, so the `print` will call. When it is not in the `a`, `print` will skip.

Comment: Your welcome. If it was helpful, you can flag it as correct answer. so other people those have same problem as you, can find it is their solution when reviewing this question on stackoverflow. It will be good if you do it in all your questions in stackoverflow.

Comment: Yes. But I think it is complicated for a person who is new in python.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `in`. When you use this with a dictionary, it checks if the value you've specified is a key in the dictionary.

```
topics = c.classify("what about ")
if "resources" in topics:
    print("yes")
```

This is the fastest and most standard way to do this. Read here for more [Python dictionary keys. "In" complexity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17539367/python-dictionary-keys-in-complexity)