# Have dictionary.get return nothing

Tags: python

I want to use dictionary.get method but to return nothing (not None) when a key is missing, is it possible without "filtering" the output:

```
d = {1:'a', 2:'b'}
vals = [1,2,3]

#I want the output to look like:
newvals = [d[v] for v in vals if v in d]
#newvals
#['a', 'b']

#But this will return default value which is None:
newvals2 = [d.get(v) for v in vals]
#>>> newvals2
#['a', 'b', None]

#(I know I can add this, but do I have to?)
#newvals2 = [val for val in newvals if val]
#['a', 'b']
```

Comment: try d[v] then d.get(v)

Comment: There's no such thing as "nothing" in Python. `None` is the closest it gets.

Comment: What's the issue with 1st approach?

Comment: Nothing really, I just want to know if it is to shorten the code with  d.get without getting the None returned.

Comment: What *value* do you consider "nothing" to be? What would be the hypothetical value of ``a = d.get(v)`` be? Why do you want to use the ``.get`` variant instead of the already working ``v in d`` variant?

Comment: He's looking for a special value that the list comprehension will automatically ignore. There isn't one.

Comment: My question is probably not well asked/defined. I just want to end up with `['a', 'b']` with the shortest possible code, and without having the code breaking when encountering a missing key

Comment: so take approach 1. There's nothing wrong with it. Btw, your vals should better be called keys, since they are keys

Comment: As far as I am aware, your first approach is the best way to do this, and it is a one-liner. How does this solution not meet your requirements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don’t want anything at all, don’t think there's a better way than this:

```
newvals2 = [d[v] for v in vals if v in d]
```

Edit: I missed you already tried it. Either way, this approach seems fine without any issue. Complexity of `in` is [O(1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17539367/python-dictionary-keys-in-complexity) anyway.

Comment: That's in the question already.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "nothing" (or `undef`) value in Python that is ignored by list comprehensions.

You can use a custom sentinel ("nothing") as the default of `get` and explicitly remove it in the same comprehension.

```py
>>> nothing = object()
>>> newvals2 = [v for k in vals if (v := d.get(k, nothing)) is not nothing]
>>> newvals2
['a', 'b']
```

Note that this is a micro-optimisation, which trades fewer `dict` lookups for a name lookup. It is not generally better than filtering by testing whether the key is in the `dict`.

Comment: I'm getting invalid syntax

Comment: What version of python are you on? @BERA

Comment: @BERA The assignment expression ``:=`` requires Python 3.8.

Comment: aha, I have 3.7.3