# compare list of objects and list of dicts

Tags: python, list, dictionary, object

I am new to Python and i've got two solutions for my problem, but i am wondering if this is the right way to do it or are there smarter solutions?

I've got a list with objects and a second list with dicts in it.
Both contains names.
I want to compare if a name is contained in both lists.

The class for the lists with objects

```
class Person():
def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name
```

Create both lists for the example

```
i = 0
while i < 100:
    person_list.append(Person("test" + str(i)))
    i += 1

search_list = list()
i = 300
while i > 0:
    search_list.append({"name": "test" + str(i)})
    i -= 1
```

Option a seems very inefficient for me, because it iterates through the whole person_list in every iteration of search_list

```
for search in search_list:
    if [p for p in person_list if p.name == search["name"]]:
        print(search["name"] + " found")
    else:
        print(search["name"] + " not found")
```

I don't want to delete something from the person_list to make the iterations shorter, because i'll reuse it later.

Option b create a new list which only contains the names before searching in search in this list

```
for search in search_list:
    if search["name"] in names:
        print(search["name"] + " found")
        names.remove(search["name"])
    else:
        print(search["name"] + " not found")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both your approaches have to scan the entire pair of lists every time (that’s what `x in some_list` inside a loop over `person_list` does).

What I’d do is traverse the list of names first, building a `dict` of names to indices.

```
from collections import defaultdict

names_to_indices = defaultdict(list)

for index, search in enumerate(search_list):
    names_to_indices[search["name"]].append(index)
```

If you don’t care about the indices, you can just use a `set` instead:

```
distinct_names = set(map(lambda search: search["name"], search_list))
```

This is one pass over the search list and requires non-constant space.

You can then iterate over your list of `Person`s, probing the `dict` or `set` for names. This will generally be a constant-time operation. So, for the price of space proportional to the number of distinct keys in `sort_list` (if you use a set; otherwise it’s proportional to the number of entries, since you’d be storing the indices) you can now perform your check in an amount of time proportional to the number of entries `n` in `person_list` (rather than in an amount of time proportional to `n * m`).

Comment: And because i've got instant access to the keys of the list i dont have to loop through the whole list, right?

Thank you for explenation, escspally that my both options do the same.

Comment: Yep: a check like `key in some_dict` or `key in some_set` will generally be a constant time operation. [You can read more about that here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4553624/hashmap-get-put-complexity) and (for Python-specific context) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17539367/python-dictionary-keys-in-complexity).

Comment: This is a common technique, but I couldn't find a good duplicate.